# How to show Grid with Add option on edit tab in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, grid, tabs, edit

I am developing a custom extension and now getting issue while showing grid on edit item tab. I want to show custom data grid with add new item option on the edit page. For details, I have attached the screenshot.
[image]

Form Class Code :

```
<?php
namespace Test\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Question\Edit\Tab;

class Main extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $store;   

    protected $helper;
    protected $_category;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
         \Test\Test\Model\Config\Source\Category $category,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->_options = $options;
        $this->_category = $category;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {

        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('ws_question');

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('question_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('General Information')]);

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('question_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'question_id']);
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'title',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'title', 'label' => __('Question'), 'title' => __(' Question'), 'required' => true]
        );

    $fieldset->addField(
            'identifier',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'identifier', 'label' => __('Identifier'), 'title' => __('Identifier'), 'required' => true]
        );

    $fieldset->addField(
            'is_active',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'is_active',
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'values' => $this->_options->getOptionArray(),
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
    $fieldset->addField(
            'category_id',
            'select',
            [
                'name'   => 'category_id',
                'label'  => __('Category'),
                'title'  => __('Category'),
                'values' => $this->_category->getCategoryOptions(),
                'required' => false
            ]
        );

    $fieldset->addField(
            'sort_order',
            'text',
            [
                'name'  => 'sort_order',
                'label' => __('Sort Order'),
                'title' => __('Sort Order'),
                'size'  => '10'
            ]
        );


      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base2_fieldset', ['legend' => __('General Information')]);
      $field = $fieldset->addField(
       'customfield',
       'text',
       [
               'name'   => 'customfield',
               'title'  => __('Custom Field'),
       ]
);

$renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
       'Test\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Question\Renderer\Customfield'
);

        $field->setRenderer($renderer);
        $this->_addElementTypes($fieldset);

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare label for tab
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Main');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare title for tab
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Main');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check permission for passed action
     *
     * @param string $resourceId
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you created that form by Ui component OR basic Magento PHP?

Comment: @kunj I have shared my form class code. I am using Magento way of form creating.